# Updating nested usercontrol after popup window close guidance

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm using telerik radgrid control with following layout:
[image: page layout]

I'm curious if anybody can provide general guidance in what approach I should take to reliably update user control that initiated popup window action?

Answer (score 0):

On radWindow OnClientClose event you can write up javascript code to reload the user control which initiated the action.

I had a somewhat similar requirement sometime ago, where I needed to rebind the grid after closing the radWindow and used the onclientclose 
    function RefreshGrid() {
    var masterTable = $find("<%= GRIDNAME.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                masterTable.rebind();
    }

In any case,  I suggest you to look into the javascript api on how to  update the user control(depends on what you want to update on the user control).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I've already have this javascript trapping window on close event but I want to update just open row but not whole grid, if I rebind grid, grid looses all open rows/tabs...

Comment: You do NOT need to rebind the whole grid. I gave you just an example. you need to look at the Javascript APIs to either refresh the radTabControl(within the radgrid row template) or if you have any specific telerik/regular asp.net control that you need to refresh inside your radtab pageview control.

Comment: Did you open a ticket with Telerik support. Their support is awesome and usually respond back in a business day. Disclaimer: I do not work for telerik. LOL

Comment: No, I didn't yet opened a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I've solve the problem:
I created "hidden" button on each tab's user control that needs to be updated and passed in button client id when opening popup. this button client id is stored as java script variable and when user close modal rad window I execute code that simulate hidden button click:

```
$find(myStoredButtonClientIdJSVariable).click();
```

That in turns execute proper user control server side code and my grid is properly refreshed.
Hope somebody might have some benefits reading this.

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't know how I'm supposed to get hold of the button id.

Right now, I do this: myWindow.add_close(onWindowClose) and then in the function onWindowClosed() I would do this clicking. However, I can't figure out how to pass the buttonId to this function! If I try to do something like myWindow.add_close(onWindowClose(buttonId)) the function just gets called right away, rather than upon closing.